# Не определяется свойство зависимости в wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Разбираюсь со свойствами зависимости. Как я понял, что бы создать свойство зависимости необходимо проделать следующие шаги (сейчас буду их сравнивать с тем что делаю я)
1)создать статическое поле типа DependencyProperty
 - создал:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushPropert
```

2) в статическом конструкторе класса - зарегистрировать свойство

- зарегистрировал:

  ```
  static MainWindow()
  {
    //регесртруем свойства зависимости
   BrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Brush", typeof(Brush), 
     typeof(InkCanvas), new PropertyMetadata(1, new 
   PropertyChangedCallback(OnCurrentBrushProperty)));
  }`
  ```

2.1) new PropertyChangedCallback
- принимает как делегат метод который будет реагировать на изменения свойства

3)создаем обычные свойства CLR

```
//свойсва CLR(обертка)
    public Brush Brush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(BrushSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BrushSizeProperty, value); }
    }
```

Хочу отметить, что вот здесь, при регистрации свойства: `Register("Brush", typeof(Brush), typeof(InkCanvas)`
 - я указал `typeof(InkCanvas)` - т.к мне необходимо, что бы данное свойство появилось у InkCanvas, но оно не определяется -почему? Вроде же все по "инструкции" делал?
 Точнее как мне обращаться к эти свойствам - напрямую, прямо на экземпляре - как к обычным свойствам  а не через SetValue и GetValue?

Comment: Регистрируете и прописываете свойства для одного класса `MainWindow`, но хотите что бы оно чудесным образом появилось в другом классе `InkCanvas`? Это так не работает, свойства создаются на том классе, в котором они прописываются. В таком случае наследуйтесь от `InkCanvas` и уже в новом классе регистрируйте нужные свойства.

Comment: `указал typeof(InkCanvas) - т.к мне необходимо, что бы данное свойство появилось у InkCanvas` а с чем вызвана данная необходимость, что вы хотите с этим `InkCanvas` сделать то?

Comment: хочу создать специальное свойство зависимости для InkCanvas с помощью которого можно менять размер кисти

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете добавить свойство в существующий класс. Так DependencyProperty не работает. Вы можете, однако, добавить attached property, возможно, вам нужно именно это.

Например, так:

```
public static class InkCanvasExtensions
{
    public static Brush GetBrush(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Brush)obj.GetValue(BrushProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBrush(DependencyObject obj, Brush value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BrushProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BrushProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Brush", typeof(Brush), typeof(InkCanvas),
            new PropertyMetadata(null, (o, args) =>
                    OnCurrentBrushChange((InkCanvas)o, (Brush)args.NewValue)));

    static void OnCurrentBrushChange(InkCanvas canvas, Brush newBrush)
    {
        // работайте с ним
    }
}
```

При этом ваш XAML будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
<InkCanvas local:InkCanvasExtensions.Brush="Black"/>
```